# Why cassandra python query result replaces column name's space with underscore?

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-driver, cassandra-python-driver

I am using cassandra python driver.
Version details :

```
[cassandra-driver (3.25.0)] 
[cqlsh 6.8.0 | Cassandra 4.0.4 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v4]
```

I am querying Cassandra database where I have created few columns which have empty space and special characters such as '%' I manage to do by supplying those columns in double quotes( ex "Mem Util %")

```
    desc my_keyspace.memutils;
    
    CREATE TABLE my_keyspace.memutils (
        time text PRIMARY KEY,
        "Mem Util %" text,
...
```

When I query those column via CQL, I supply the column name with double quotes and I get proper data as well as my result columns are as it is, example :

```
select "Mem Util %" from my_keyspace.memutils;

 Mem Util %
----------------------
          9.177055477
          83.85167852
```

But when I use Cassandra-python driver, the query is able to get the proper data but it replaces spaces in the column's name with underscore in the result data(ResponseFeature)

Code snippet

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.policies import DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
...

print("Select query--> ", fetch_query)
response_future = self.session.execute(fetch_query);
...
print('response_future  --> ', response_future[0])
```

Output

```
Select query-->  select Time, "Mem Util %" from my_keyspace.memutils;
response_future-->  Row(time='631', Mem_Util='9.177055477')
```

The result data set also doesn't' have "%" in the column.

Question :

1. Is there any option in session.execute(), to disable above behavior ?

I saw [doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/api/cassandra/query/)

Comment: IT could be because you are using default named_tuple_factory as a row_factory. Attributes of a named tuple must be valid Python identifiers, so column names get transformed. You can try dict_factory, maybe that will use original column name.